# При выводе кнопок выбора города, не могу заблокировать возможность ввода текса

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, при выводе кнопок выбора города я не могу заблокировать возможность ввода текса.

```py
def city(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    user_data['city'] = message.text
    logger.info(f"Пользователь {user_id} указал город: {message.text}")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Спасибо! Теперь введите свой номер телефона", reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, problem)

def get_city_keyboard():
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, selective=True)
    city_list = [
        "Москва", "Санкт-Петербург", "Екатеринбург",
        "Новосибирск", "Красноярск", "Казань", "Самара", "Волгоград",
        "Ростов-на-Дону", "Нижний Новгород", "Краснодар", "Уфа",
        "Воронеж", "Ижевск", "Сочи", "Омск", "Челябинск", "Пермь",
        "Ростов", "Ульяновск", "Тула", "Томск", "Саратов", "Тюмень",
        "Владимир"
    ]

    columns = 2
    current_column = 0
    row = []

    for city in city_list:
        row.append(city)
        current_column += 1
        if current_column >= columns:
            markup.row(*row)
            row = []
            current_column = 0

    if row:
        markup.row(*row)

    return markup
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)